# Android : How create an event in calendar other than Splanner from Samsung

Tags: c#, android, events, calendar, xamarin.android

I am currently trying to solve an issue with Android.
My problem is, my next code can creates an Event in SPlanner (Samsung shedule).
When i try to create an event in Calendar(Motorolla, Nexus ... etc), it creates an Anniversary Event and removes this one few seconde later.

Here is my code to add an event :

```
 var calendarId = this.GetDefaultCalendarId();
        var values = new ContentValues();
        values.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.CalendarId, calendarId);
        values.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Title, "title");
        values.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.EventLocation, adresse);
        values.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtstart, this.GetDateTimeMs(startDate));
        values.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtend, this.GetDateTimeMs(endDate));
        values.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.EventTimezone, Java.Util.TimeZone.Default.ID);
        var uri = Context.ContentResolver.Insert(CalendarContract.Events.ContentUri, values);
        var eventId = Java.Lang.Integer.ParseInt(uri.LastPathSegment);
```

If anyone has any idea, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. 
It was the calendarId and its value. 
So, when you try to get the calendarId you have to check the value cause :
1 = Anniversary and 3 = normal event.